# Bootstrap 3: different glyphicons than expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Im getting different glyphicons than expected..I have bs 3.0.2. For example the user icon shows a circle..

I installed Bootstrap using composer: https://packagist.org/packages/twitter/bootstrap

```
.glyphicon {
display: inline-block;
font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
font-size: 51px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 2;
position: relative;
top: 1px;
}
.glyphicon-asterisk:before {
content: "*";
}
.glyphicon-plus:before {
content: "+";
}
.glyphicon-euro:before {
content: "€";
}
.glyphicon-minus:before {
content: "−";
}
.glyphicon-cloud:before {
content: "☁";
}
.glyphicon-envelope:before {
content: "✉";
}
.glyphicon-pencil:before {
content: "✏";
}
.glyphicon-glass:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-music:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-search:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-heart:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-star:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-star-empty:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-user:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-film:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-th-large:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-th:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-th-list:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-ok:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-remove:before {
content: "";
}
.glyphicon-zoom-in:before {
```

Comment: I don't see a circle in this `user` example; probably because I don't have the font installed. Can you clarify with an image? Also: *where* are you "getting different glyphicons than expected"?

Comment: For Bootstrap 3, Glyphicons should install as icon font files in your ../fonts/ directory. To use the user Glyphicon you'd just have something like <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>. What is the CSS you're including in your question?